# Как получить callable атрибуты у объекта?

Tags: python, ооп

На первый взгляд ответ на этот вопрос очень простой. Обратиться к полю `__dict__` и отфильтровать по свойству `callable`. Проблема в том, что у объекта определено поле `__slots__`, что не даёт этого сделать.
Есть ли какой-нибудь иной способ получить имена всех методов класса, не переписывая сам класс, имею в виду удаления поля `__slots__`?

**Update** @S.Nick

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import Dict


class Abstract(ABC):
    __slots__ = set()

    def __init__(self, attributes: Dict):
        attributes = {k: v for (k, v) in attributes.items() if k in self.__slots__}
        for attr, val in attributes.items():
            setattr(self, attr, val)


class A(Abstract):
    __slots__ = {'a', 'b'}

    def method1(self):
        return 'method1'

    def method2(self):
        return 'method2'


class B(Abstract):
    __slots__ = {'c', 'd'}

    def method3(self):
        return 'method3'

    def method4(self):
        return 'method4'


class Combiner:
    def __init__(self, data: Dict):
        self.met1 = A(data)
        self.met2 = B(data)
    
    def get_method(self, func_name):
        pass
```

Хочу чтобы метод `get_method` по имени функции возвращал соответствующий метод из классов `A` и `B`. То есть:

```
>>> g = Combiner()
>>> g.get_method('method2')
    <bound method A.method2 of <__main__.A object at 0x10f520438>>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick дополнил минимальным воспроизводимым примером.

Answer (score 5):

Если задача - получить именно методы (а не вообще все callable аттрибуты), то можно так:

```
class Example:
    
    __slots__ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    
    
    def foo():
        pass
    
    def bar():
        pass
    

example = Example()

import inspect

methods = inspect.getmembers(example, predicate=inspect.ismethod)

print([name for name, method in methods])
```

Если же хочется вообще все callable аттрибуты, то замените `predicate=inspect.ismethod` на `predicate=callable`

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
class my:
    __slots__ = "a", "b"
    def foo(self):
        pass

for el in dir(my):
    if callable(getattr(my, el)):
        print(el)
```

если магические методы не нужны, то так:

```
for el in dir(my):
    if callable(getattr(my, el)) and not el.startswith("__"):
        print(el)
```